# What is the best way to get ping by an external api in a development environnement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm developing a rail application who need to get ping by the HeyWatch api :

http://wiki.heywatch.com/API+Documentation+Ping+Examples

I'm wondering what is the best and simplest way to get ping in my local development environnement?  Right now I'm working with WEBrick.

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [HeyWatch](https://github.com/nel/heywatch) gem?

Comment: yes already use it.  My problem is more about creating a development environment for application that play nicely with ping from external api.  Do I need to open up my router and reroute trafic to my rails server?

Comment: Yes you'll have to open a port on your firewall and forward it to your local machine.

Comment: Is it a normal pratice to port forward to a webrick server?  Is it safe?

Comment: I've never had to do it. You can lock down the forwarding though and only accept requests from HeyWatch and then it should be decently secure.

Comment: I'd ask this on ServerFault if you want 'server security' advice.